# Elastic Beanstalk + Laravel: Can't run Gulp because of old NodeJS Version 0.10

Tags: node.js, laravel, amazon-web-services, gulp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try to deploy a Laravel repo on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. For this I've created a PHP environment on a t2.medium instance and initialized a deployment with AWS CodePipeline.

I need to run `npm` and `gulp` on production for creating my static assets, but unfortunately I'm not able to run NPM because of an old NodeJS version installed. It's `0.10.46-1nodesource.el7.centos`.

At the moment I'm using two config scripts to install NodeJS 10.X, run the migrations and gulp:

First:

```
commands:
  01getNodeRepo:
    command: "curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -"
  02installNode:
    command: "yum install -y nodejs"
  03updateNpm:
    command: "npm install npm -g"
  04enableSudo:
    command: "echo Defaults:root \\!requiretty >> /etc/sudoers"
```

Second:

```
container_commands:
  01artisanMigrate:
    command: "php artisan migrate --force"
  02showNodeVersion:
    command: "node -v"
  03showNpmVersion:
    command: "npm -v"
  04npmInstall:
    command: "sudo npm install"
  05gulp:
    command: "sudo ./node_modules/.bin/gulp --production"
```

Here is an extract from my log files which shows that AWS EB found two `nodesource` repos and will be using the old version:

```
[2019-01-01T19:32:23.008Z] INFO  [1535]  - [Application update code-pipeline-xx-xxx@17/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/xxxx/Command 02installNode] : Starting activity...
[2019-01-01T19:32:25.314Z] INFO  [1535]  - [Application update code-pipeline-xx-xxx@17/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild/xxxx/Command 02installNode] : Completed activity. Result:
  Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
  Repository nodesource is listed more than once in the configuration
  Repository nodesource-source is listed more than once in the configuration
  Resolving Dependencies
  --> Running transaction check
  ---> Package nodejs.x86_64 0:0.10.46-1nodesource.el7.centos will be installed
  --> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

Any ideas how I can force the environment to use the new version? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got it. This was the solution: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/421#issuecomment-318560799

```
rm -f /etc/yum.repos.d/nodesource-el.repo
yum clean all
yum -y remove nodejs
yum -y install nodejs
```